# Importing Urdu data-set in R

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to import such data-set in R. But it is giving me error. Am I doing anything wrong?

***Code:***

```
library(rio)
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Urdu") 
fil <- read.csv("D:/PycharmProjects/shiny-examples-master/shiny-examples-master/Data_set.csv",encoding='UTF-8')
```

***Data_set.csv:***

```
Reg No.     address
13  Nazim ud Din Road, F-11, ICT, وفاقی دارالحکومت اسلام آباد, 44000, ‏پاکستان‎
45  Street 34, F-7/1, F-7, ICT, وفاقی دارالحکومت اسلام آباد, 44000, ‏پاکستان‎
5564    Lane 11, DHA Phase II, ICT, وفاقی دارالحکومت اسلام آباد, 44000, ‏پاکستان‎
```

***Error:***

```
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
5: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
6: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'D:/PycharmProjects/shiny-examples-master/shiny-examples-master/12000.csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file may be encoded in unicode (which can contain `zero bytes`), so you'll likely have to use `utf-16` instead of `"Urdu"`, and/or `encoding='UTF-16'` in the `read.csv()` call.

Also, the delimiter is `tab`. Make sure to provide that as a parameter in case the reader defaults to `,`: `sep = '\t'`.